# Make the page title H1 automatically in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

On two of my wordpress sites the **page/post** title is not automatically assigned the H1 tag.

I'm assume, I need to change the `CSS` templates for this.

Does anyone know, where to change the theme or CSS, so that the page/post title automatically becomes the `H1` tag as well?

Thank you

Comment: You will need to look at the PHP/HTML being used by your theme. We don't know what theme you're using, so we can't tell you where the change needs to happen, but you should search for the [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function which displays the title in WordPress themes. However, you shouldn't blindly edit your theme files because those files might be replaced in future updates to the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your php files in the theme folder (`\wp-content\themes`) to modify an H1 since the css only gives styles to it.

Comment: Haha why is this downvoted? It's an vague answer to an equally vague question that could definitely be correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
<?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>
```